# Getting location data in initState

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I need to get location data which is used to calculate the distance between the user and other locations. This is on the app's home page and I don't want to do this every time the page loads, that's why I set up a timestamp and the location is grabbed only if five minutes pass.

What I have now is something like this in the home page:

```
  LocationData _currentPosition;


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getLocationData();
  }

  _getLocationData() async {
    final content = Provider.of<Content>(context.read());

    final _timestamp = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
    final _contentTimestamp = content.homeTimestamp;

    if ((_contentTimestamp == null) ||
        ((_timestamp) - _contentTimestamp) >= 300000) {
      try {
        _locationData = await location.getLocation();
        content.homeTimestamp = _timestamp;
        setState(() {
          _currentPosition = _locationData;
        });
      } on Exception catch (exception) {
        print(exception);
      } catch (error) {
        print(error);
      }
    }
  }
```

And I store the timestamp in `Provider` because I want it to persist when the user leaves the home page and returns. Not sure how to set it up without `notifyListeners()`

```
  int _homeTimestamp;
  int get homeTimestamp => _homeTimestamp;
  set homeTimestamp(int newValue) {
    _homeTimestamp = newValue;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

My problem is that sometimes the location doesn't get stored and the page doesn't load. Is there a better way to do this?

I was thinking of adding a FutureBuilder in the body, but that would mean that the location will be retrieved every time the user loads the page, or I can just do the timestamp check in the body and not load the `FutureBuilder` all the time, but that doesn't seem right.

```
body: _currentPosition == null
        ? Center(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20.0,
                  width: 20.0,
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 10.0,
                ),
                Text("Getting your location..."),
              ],
            ),
          )
        : Column(
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

use shared preference to check if the _getLocationData() method is called and use Timer.periodic(); method to call the function every five minutes.